# ExpandoObject working differently in vb.net then in c#

Tags: vb.net, facebook, expandoobject

after converting some code fron here https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winforms-sample the isnt acseptig code like `parameters.client_id`

here is the section im haveing problems with

```
Private Function GenerateLoginUrl(ByVal appId As String, ByVal extendedPermissions As String) As Uri
        Dim parameters As New ExpandoObject() =
        parameters.client_id = appId
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"

        ' The requested response: an access token (token), an authorization code (code), or both (code token).
        parameters.response_type = "token"

        ' list of additional display modes can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display
        parameters.display = "popup"

        ' add the 'scope' parameter only if we have extendedPermissions.
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions) Then
            parameters.scope = extendedPermissions
        End If

        ' when the Form is loaded navigate to the login url.
        Return _fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the equals sign on the end of the line `Dim parameters As New ExpandoObject()`